# Añadir Persona a lista en C

Tags: c, lista, insert

no consigo que se agregue los datos de una persona en una lista. La lista tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
typedef char Cadena [30];
struct Persona{
    int         NumeroDNI;
    Cadena      Nombre;
    Cadena      Apellido;
};
struct Lista{
    int         Num;
    struct      Persona Datos[10];
};
```

La funcion que estoy usando es:

```
void insertar(struct Lista *l){
        printf("Introduzca el DNI, el nombre y el apellido de la persona:\n");
        scanf("%d %s %s", &(lista->Datos[lista->Num].NumeroDNI), lista->Datos[lista->Num].Nombre,  lista->Datos[lista->Num].Apellido);
        l->Num++;
    }
}
```

Este es inicio:

```
int main(){
struct Persona l;
    l.Num = 0;
int opcion;
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen("Personas.txt","r");
    while(!feof(fichero))
    {
        fscanf(fichero,"%d %s %s", &(l.Datos[i].NumeroDNI), l.Datos[i].Nombre, l.Datos[i].Apellido);
        l.Num++;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fichero);
    do{
     printf("Elige opcion: \n1. Mostrar\n2. Insertar\n0. Terminar);
     scanf("%d",&opcion);
     switch(opcion){
      case 1:{
       mostrar(&l);
       break;
       }   
      case 2:{ 
       insertar(&l);
       break;
       }  
    }
    while(opcion!=0);
    return 0;
}
```

El problema está cuando se añade a otra persona ya que no se guarda, mostrar(struct Persona *l) está bien definida por eso no la copio, simplemente muestra la lista al completo. Si por ejemplo añado 71422247 Pedro Garcia, y luego selecciono mostrar aparece la lista sin añadir y en el lugar donde debería ir Pedro aparece letras y números aleatorios.

Muchas gracias.

**SOLUCIONADO**

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: El problema es que no se guarda esa persona en la lista

Comment: ¿Qué significa "*no se guarda*"? ¿Qué datos introduces y qué datos recibes de salida y cuáles esperabas recibir?

Comment: Cuando añado a alguien y luego muestro la lista me aparece letras y números aleatorios en los huecos donde deberían estar los datos introducidos

Comment: En la función main haces esto: `struct Persona l;
    l.Num = 0;`

Comment: Cuando debería ser: `struct Lista l;
    l.Num = 0;` :) ¿Qué compilador estás usando? Es raro que el compilador no dé error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que ha un fallo en la declaración de la lista y tendría que ser así:

```
struct Lista{
   int     Num;
   Persona Datos[10];
};
```

Luego tu función insertar sería así:

```
void insertaro(struct Persona *l)
{
    printf("Introduzca el DNI, el nombre y el apellido de la persona:\n");
    scanf("%d %s %s", &(lista->Datos[lista->Num].NumeroDNI), 
                      &(lista->Datos[lista->Num].Nombre),  
                      &(lista->Datos[lista->Num].Apellido));
    /* Reflejamos que hemos añadido un elemento más a la lista */
    lista->Num++;
}
```

}

Comment: Pues depende... puede que `Num` inicialmente valga -1... o que no esté inicializada... vete tu a saber.

Comment: Si ya Persona es un tipo de dato declarado, para qué precisas la palabra clave struct  . Cuanto declaras Point A, no declaras como struct Point A por ya Point es un tipo de dato.

Comment: Debe ser `struct Persona Datos[10]`.. Porque en la definición de la estructura no usó el typedef, de lo contrario, si no antepone el struct dará error el compilador. Esto solo es en C, en C++ no hay problema. Cuidado compilas ese ejemplo en un compilador de C++..

Comment: Ok, no le veía sentido inicialmente.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores.

El primero es que declaras una funcion `insertar`, que toma una variable de tipo puntero a `struct Persona` y la tratas como si fuera una lista. Primero incrementas su número de elementos (campo que una persona no tiene) y luego insertas la persona en otra lista, ni siquiera la que pasas como argumento.

Intentas meter los datos leídos en una estructura persona, en vez de en una lista.

Cambia la declaración por:

```
void insertar(struct Lista * l);
```

El otro error que tienes es que te saltas el primer elemento, es decir, insertas el primer elemento en la segunda posición de la lista, el segundo elemento en la tercera posición, y así.

También puede deberse a no inicializar los campos de la estructura `struct Persona` o bien de la lista, como el campo `Num`. En C siempre debes inicializar los campos (puede que ya lo hayas hecho).

También te recomiendo separar la lectura por teclado de la inserción en la lista, y sobre todo seguir las convenciones de C, como que las variables empiezan en minúscula.

En cualquier caso, el incremento del campo `Num` se debe hacer después de la inserción, ya que sino, te saltas el primer espacio (un vector con N elementos tiene índices de 0 a N-1).

Con todo lo comentado, el código quedaría algo así.

```
void insertarPersonaEnLista(struct Persona * p, struct Lista * l)
{
    l->datos[l->num].numeroDni = p->numeroDni;
    l->datos[l->num].nombre = p->nombre;
    l->datos[l->num].apellido = p->apellido;
    l->num++;
}

// ...

struct Lista lista = crearLista();
struct Persona persona = leerPersona();
insertarPersonaEnLista(&persona, &lista);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!